# Multi GPU Training in Tensorflow (Data Parallelism) when Using feed_dict

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use multiple GPUs to train my Tensorflow model taking advantage of data parallelism.

I am currently training a Tensorflow model using the following approach:

```
x_ = tf.placeholder(...)
y_ = tf.placeholder(...)
y = model(x_)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y_, logits=y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = tf.contrib.training.create_train_op(loss, optimizer)
for i in epochs:
   for b in data:
      _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x_: b.x, y_: b.y})
```

I would like to take advantage of multiple GPUs to train this model in a data parallelize manner. i.e. I would like to split my batches in half and run each half batch on one of my two GPUs.

[cifar10_multi_gpu_train](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) seems to provide a good example of creating a loss that draws from graphs running on multiple GPUs, but I haven't found a good examples of doing this style of training when using `feed_dict` and `placeholder` as opposed to a data loader queue.

*UPDATE*

Seems like: https://timsainb.github.io/multi-gpu-vae-gan-in-tensorflow.html might provide a good example. They seem to pull in `average_gradients` from `cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py` and create one placeholder which they then slice into for each of the GPUs. 
I think you also need to split `create_train_op` into three stages: `compute_gradients`, `average_gradients` and then `apply_gradients`.

Comment: I've managed to reuse the cifar example on mnist. It's slow and the results are not exciting. https://github.com/normanheckscher/mnist-multi-gpu

Comment: Your case looks very similar to the example on this page: https://github.com/vahidk/EffectiveTensorflow. The second example of make parallel should work for you.

Comment: @BoShao - could you move your comment to an answer?  Or, Alex, did you manage to answer your own question with the link you found and we should turn it into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I know three ways of feeding data on multi-gpu model.

1. if all your inputs are of same shape, you may build placeholder `x` on CPU, then use `tf.split` to split `x` into `xs`. Then on each tower of GPU, get `xs[i]` as your input.

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="encoder_inputs")
    encoder_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,], name="encoder_length")

    # make sure batch % num_gpu == 0
    inputs = tf.split(encoder_inputs, axis=0)  # axis=0, split on batch dimension
    lens = tf.split(encoder_length, axis=0)

with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for i in range(num_gpus):
        with tf.device("/gpu:%d"%i):
            with tf.name_scope("tower_%d"%i):
                loss = compute_loss(inputs[i], lens[i])
```

2. if your inputs have different shape, you need to build placeholder `x` on every GPU with a scope.

```
def init_placeholder(self):
    with tf.variable_scope("inputs"):   # use a scope
        encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="encoder_inputs")
        encoder_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,], name="encoder_length")
    return encoder_inputs, encoder_length

with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for g, gpu in enumerate(GPUS):
        with tf.device("/gpu:%d"%gpu):
            with tf.name_scope("tower_%d"%g):
                x, x_len = model.init_placeholder()  # these placeholder Tensor are on GPU
                loss = model.compute_loss(x, x_len)
```

3. use `tf.data.Dataset` to feed data. google official `cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py` use `Queue`, which is similar with this way.